# If the methods need to be called, why the update(Graphics g) method can run automatically?

Tags: java, loops

Example: When we create a JFrame in a main method, and override the update, we do not need to call the update at the instance of the Jframe to start the loop, this method begin automatically, why? What is calling the update?

For Example:

```
        public class Example extends JPanel{
        public Example(){
setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);}
            @Override
            public void update(Graphics g) {  
                paint(g);
        System.out.println("The method update is always being running, but I never call it at main method!")

            }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillOval(0, 0, 40, 40);

                g.dispose();
                repaint();
            }
        public static void main(String[]args){
        Example example = new Example();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Why?");
        frame.add(example);
        frame.pack();  
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `update()` method it what is known as a "callback". It is called by the Swing library. Similarly `paint()` is also a callback that Swing will call automatically.

Note that in "modern" Swing, you should override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`.